# Programmatically selecting a sub-makefile to include when running make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, cp

I have the following logic in a Makefile:

```
ifdef INCLUDE_FILE
$(shell cp  $(INCLUDE_FILE) include.make)
else
$(shell cp -n default.make include.make)
endif

include include.make
```

The intended behavior is:

- If one just runs `make` and `include.make` exists, `include.make` is included. Otherwise, a default file is copied to `include.make` and then included.
- If one runs `make INCLUDE_FILE=myinclude.make`, then `myinclude.make` is copied and included.

This seems to work fine to allow makefile customizations (compiler flags, etc) in `include.make`, which will persist if one does something like

```
$make INCLUDE_FILE=myinclude.make
$...
$make
```

but also allow a new user to simply type `make` and see default behavior.

My questions are

- Is this good/standard (gnu) makefile practice?
- Are there any serious portability concerns? [That is, is relying on `cp` in this way dangerous?]
- Is there a better alternative method to implement similar behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If the intention of this is to persist then I think this idea is reasonable though I wouldn't implement it this way.

I'd probably do something like this instead.

```
include include.mk

include.mk:
        @cp $(or $(INCLUDE_FILE),default.mk) $@
```

Assuming you want the copy to only happen once (unless `include.mk` is manually deleted). There are other ways this could be done to handle copying again (if `default.mk` changes, etc. but those require more information about your goal).

The simplest (albeit hack) way to get `make INCLUDE_FILE=myinclude.mk` to always copy over `include.mk` is likely to add something like the following to the above makefile snippet.

```
ifdef INCLUDE_FILE
.PHONY: $(INCLUDE_FILE)

include.mk: $(INCLUDE_FILE)
endif
```

Though this does copy the file multiple times. You could add a check on `$(MAKE_RESTARTS)` also to avoid that.

include include.mk

```
include.mk:
        cp $(or $(INCLUDE_FILE),default.mk) $@

ifdef INCLUDE_FILE
ifndef MAKE_RESTARTS
.PHONY: $(INCLUDE_FILE)

include.mk: $(INCLUDE_FILE)
endif
endif
```

This is slightly abusive of the behaviour of a normal target when it specifies a `.PHONY` target as a prerequisite but it seems to work and is, I believe, only depending on documented behaviour.

Comment: I would like the copy to happen if  `include.mk` does not exist  and also if `INCLUDE_FILE` is specified explicitly. Specifically, I would like `make INCLUDE_FILE=myinclude.mk` to always overwrite `include.mk`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use:

```
INCLUDE_FILE := $(firstword $(wildcard include.make default.make))

include $(INCLUDE_FILE)
```

?  This will include either `include.make`, if it exists, or else `default.make`, or if you define `INCLUDE_FILE` on the command line it will override the setting in the makefile.

Comment: This is very close to the behavior I would like, except that I believe that if I run `make INCLUDE_FILE=myinclude.make;  ... work work work ..; make`, the second `make` will include include the commands in `default.make`, not the commands in `myinclude.make`. That is, I would like for `include.make` to exist as persistent configuration, which (naively at least) seems to require some interaction with the filesystem.